# error parsing JSON object in blackberry

Tags: java, php, json, blackberry

My php as follows:

```
<?php
$str = '{
"name": "10.000000,106.000000",
"Status": {
"code": 200,
"request": "geocode"
 },
   "Apps": [ {
"Thread1": 1,
"Thread2": 1   
"Thread3": 1
"Thread4": 1
"Thread5": 1
"Thread6": 1
"Thread7": 1
} ]
}';
echo $str;
?>
```

When I try to get "Apps" array, I get the following exception:

```
Exception: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 165 of {
"name": "10.000000,106.000000",
"Status": {
"code": 200,
"request": "geocode"
},
"Apps": [ {
 "Thread1": 1,
 "Thread2": 1   
"Thread3": 1
"Thread4": 1
"Thread5": 1
"Thread6": 1
"Thread7": 1
} ]
}
```

Can anybody help/point me where I'm wrong in specifing the JSONArray? Thanks.

Comment: how you parsing the json ?

Comment: @catherine you should take a look at my answer - manually creating the JSON string is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no commas after "ThreadX": 1 ?

check this: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

it seems you forgot the commas behind the THREAD2 ... THREAD6 statements,

just use http://jsonlint.com/ to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Try : forgot `,` after thread 2 ... so on.

```
<?php
$str = '{
"name": "10.000000,106.000000",
"Status": {
"code": 200,
"request": "geocode"
 },
   "Apps": [ {
"Thread1": 1,
"Thread2": 1,   
"Thread3": 1,
"Thread4": 1,
"Thread5": 1,
"Thread6": 1,
"Thread7": 1
} ]
}';

$arr = json_decode($str);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be manually creating JSON with strings. This is a bad idea because you can easily break the JSON format (as you have) and you need to ensure you properly escape the quotes. Instead you should build the data in a PHP structure and then use `json_encode()` to create the actual JSON string:

```
$array = array(
    'name' => '10.000000,106.000000',
    'Status' => array(
        'code' => 200,
        'request' => 'geocode'
    ),
    'Apps' => array(
        array(
            'Thread1' => 1,
            'Thread2' => 1,
            'Thread3' => 1,
            'Thread4' => 1,
            'Thread5' => 1,
            'Thread6' => 1,
            'Thread7' => 1
        )
    )
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = '{
"name": "10.000000,106.000000",
"Status": {
"code": 200,
"request": "geocode"
 },
   "Apps": [ {
"Thread1": 1,
"Thread2": 1,   
"Thread3": 1,
"Thread4": 1,
"Thread5": 1,
"Thread6": 1,
"Thread7": 1
} ]
}';
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($str,true));
echo "<pre/>"; 
?>
```

Out put :

```
Array
(
    [name] => 10.000000,106.000000
    [Status] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [request] => geocode
        )

    [Apps] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Thread1] => 1
                    [Thread2] => 1
                    [Thread3] => 1
                    [Thread4] => 1
                    [Thread5] => 1
                    [Thread6] => 1
                    [Thread7] => 1
                )

        )

)
```